# Как открыть ранее созданный текстовый файл в С++?

Tags: c++, файлы

Если я хочу открыть определенный файл, лежащий в директории с моей программой, то я пишу такой код:

```
ofstream fout;
fout.open("test.txt");
if (fout.is_open())
{
    fout << "Test text";
    cout << "Output operation successfully performed\n";
    fout.close();
}
else
{
    cout << "Error opening file";
}
```

А что мне делать, если я хочу, чтобы пользователь сам выбирал имя файла, открывал ранее созданные файлы?

Comment: Спросите у пользователя имя файла и передайте его в `fout.open()`...

Comment: @Harry создать строку,ввести ее и поместить в fout.open()?

Comment: Ну вот, вы же сами все понимаете :)

Answer (score -1):

```
string path;
cout << "Enter file's path: ";
cin.getline(path,100);
ofstream fout;
fout.open(path);
```